# How to parse multiple variables via ng-click into a angularjs function

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and can't seem to figure out how to parse multiple variables from a html button thru an angular JS function.

```
<html ng-app="">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <body ng-controller='CartController'>

    <script>
      function CartController($scope) {
        $scope.addToCart = function(index,product) {
          alert(product);
        };
      }
    </script>

    <button ng-click="addToCart(2,iPhone);">Add to cart</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

I would expect the second variable (iPhone) would get stored in variable named product but the alert shows its undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ng-click="addToCart(2,'iPhone');"`

What you want is to pass the string `'iPhone'`, not a property on the `$scope` called `iPhone`.

Without the quotes, it will be evaluated against the `$scope` in `CartController`. There is no `iPhone` property on `$scope` so it will be `undefined`.

Your original try would work if in `CartController` you'd have:

```
$scope.iPhone = "Hello";
```

The string `Hello` would be passed to the `addToCart` function.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs, this solved the problem. Now that I know it was a bit obvious.